# Serial Communication issues with python and TI

Tags: python, serial-port, uart, xbee

I have an XBee (S2C) connected to my Mac and another XBee connected to a TI microcontroller (TIVA-C129) communicating with each other - Mac as a coordinator and TI as a router.

I can communicate between them, but on the TI side, I can't read the exact data that is coming in the serial port.

On the Mac, I am running below python code that reads the incoming serial data through XBee and writes an acknowledgment.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import serial

ser = serial.Serial('/dev/tty.usbserial-A104IC2U', 9600)
ack='A'

while True:
    incoming = ser.readline().strip()
    if incoming != 'A':
        print '%s' % incoming
        ser.write('%s\n' % ack)
```

On the TI side, I have below code

```
int incomingByte = 0;   

void setup()
{
  Serial3.begin(9600); //UART3 has XBee connection
  pinMode(LED, OUTPUT);    
}

void loop()
{
  Serial3.println("Sending command to the XBee");
  delay(1000);
  Serial3.println("I am R1");
  delay(1000);

  if (Serial3.available() > 0) {
                // read the incoming byte from UART3
                incomingByte = Serial3.read();

                // say what you got, print at the usb serial console
                Serial.print("I received: ");   
                Serial.println(incomingByte, DEC);

        }

}
```

When I run this, XBee communication stops after printing "**I am R1"** in the python console. I am sure **Serial3.available() > 0** is working as when I replace it with a blink code like below, it works and XBee communication keeps working on.

```
if (Serial3.available() > 0) {

                digitalWrite(LED, HIGH);   // turn the LED on (HIGH is the voltage level)
                delay(1000);               // wait for a second
                digitalWrite(LED, LOW);    // turn the LED off by making the voltage LOW
                delay(1000);               // wait for a second
        }
```

So looks like the problem is in

```
incomingByte = Serial3.read();
```

From python, I am sending a string (%s) with `ser.write('%s\n' % ack)`. Is **Serial3.read()** the right read mechanism for the **ack** string? Anything else?

FYI: I tested the serial.read() only with TI (no python involved) by writing something in the console and serial.read() can read and print it.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible you're getting stuck on the `Serial.print()` on the TI side, maybe because you have hardware handshaking enabled for that port and it's waiting on CTS/RTS?

If you comment out those lines, does the program work?  You could use strategically placed `digitalWrite()` calls to figure out how far you get inside of `loop()`.

Also, I see that you're printing `"Sending command to the XBee"` to `Serial3`, so you should see that on the Python side as well.

Finally, you might want to change your `if` to a `while`, so your loop function processes all of the inbound bytes before getting stuck in the two one-second delays on each pass of the loop (limiting throughput to a single character every two seconds).